# htaccess append query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I would like apache to redirect all requests to a file to the same url with a query string.

From this:
 /images/all/1.jpg

To this:
/images/all/1.jpg?ver=1

I was trying like this, but it does nothing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$/
RewriteRule ^/images/all/1\.jpg$ /images/all/1.jpg?ver=1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^images/all/1\.jpg$ %{REQUEST_URI}?ver=1 [R=302,NE,L]
```